# Is there a way to create 2D mesh in PyMesh automatically based on cell size?

Tags: python, mesh

While reading the docs of [`PyMesh`](http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#accessing-mesh-data), I found only two ways to generate a mesh, the first is loading an external mesh file and the second is using raw data where the vertex array and faces are used to create the mesh.

I was wondering if I could just enter the boundary vertices and specify a maximum cell/face size to generate the mesh automatically ([just like this example in dolphin](https://fenicsproject.org/documentation/dolfin/1.4.0/python/demo/documented/mesh-generation/python/documentation.html))?

```
#The dolfin example which I need to mimic in PyMesh
from dolfin import *

# Create empty Mesh 
mesh = Mesh()

# Create list of polygonal domain vertices 
domain_vertices = [Point(0.0, 0.0),
                   Point(10.0, 0.0),
                   Point(10.0, 2.0),
                   Point(8.0, 2.0),
                   Point(7.5, 1.0),
                   Point(2.5, 1.0),
                   Point(2.0, 4.0),
                   Point(0.0, 4.0),
                   Point(0.0, 0.0)]

# Generate mesh and plot 
PolygonalMeshGenerator.generate(mesh, domain_vertices, 0.25) 
plot(mesh, interactive=True)
```

The result mesh:

[image]